# Where to configure the detecting range of urg_node?

Tags: ros, urg-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, guys,

I am using hokuyo UTM-30LX EW laser. I can set the parameters in my launch files, such as "ip_address", "angle_min", "angle_max" and so on, shown in [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node). But how to set the detecting range in launch file or someother place? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204833/where-to-configure-the-detecting-range-of-urg_node?/) by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2015-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-03-12**:
I'm not familiar with a detection range setting for the Hokuyo. Can you provide a link to the manufacturer's documentation or an excerpt describing the parameter you want to set?

**Comment by [tony](https://answers.ros.org/users/2149/tony/) on 2015-03-12**:
@ahendrix The laser I used is Hokuyo UTM-30LX EW. I hope to set the minimum and maximum detecting range. I don't know how to set them for urg_node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use the LaserScanRangeFilter of the laser_filters package.

http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanRangeFilter

---

Originally posted by [JorgeArino](https://answers.ros.org/users/20071/jorgearino/) with karma: 96 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0